# Moodle enrol_manual_enrol_users doesn't work

Tags: php, web-services, rest, moodle

I try to enrol users in a course using `Moodle Rest API` method `enrol_manual_enrol_users()`, but it's don't create anything in the `mdl_role_assignments` table.

```php
    /// Connection
    $token = 'ed874e6d9f51239e180f49f4d926d50f';
    $domainname = 'http://localhost/moodle';
    $functionname = 'enrol_manual_enrol_users';
    $restformat = 'json';

    //////// enrol_manual_enrol_users ////////

    /// Paramètres
    $enrolment = new stdClass();
    $enrolment->roleid = 5; //estudante(student) -> 5; moderador(teacher) -> 4; professor(editingteacher) -> 3;
    $enrolment->userid = 2;
    $enrolment->courseid = 5; 
    $enrolments = array( $enrolment);
    $params = array('enrolments' => $enrolments);

    print_r($params);

    header('Content-Type: text/plain');

    $serverurl = $domainname . '/webservice/rest/server.php'. '?wstoken=' . $token . '&wsfunction='.$functionname;
    require_once('./curl.php');
    $curl = new curl;
    //if rest format == 'xml', then we do not add the param for backward compatibility with Moodle < 2.2
    $restformat = ($restformat == 'json')?'&moodlewsrestformat=' . $restformat:'';
    $resp = $curl->post($serverurl . $restformat, $params);
    print_r($resp);
```

I need a way to enroll users in moodle courses by webservice...

**UPDATE**

The following response is returned:

```
    "debuginfo":"Missing required key in single structure: enrolments"
```

The parameters are

```php
    'roleid' => new external_value(PARAM_INT, 'Role to assign to the user'),
    'userid' => new external_value(PARAM_INT, 'The user that is going to be enrolled'),
    'courseid' => new external_value(PARAM_INT, 'The course to enrol the user role in'),
    'timestart' => new external_value(PARAM_INT, 'Timestamp when the enrolment start', VALUE_OPTIONAL),
    'timeend' => new external_value(PARAM_INT, 'Timestamp when the enrolment end', VALUE_OPTIONAL),
    'suspend' => new external_value(PARAM_INT, 'set to 1 to suspend the enrolment', VALUE_OPTIONAL)
```

The userid and the courseid are valids id's

Comment: Have you turned on debugging ( http://docs.moodle.org/en/Debugging ) for the site, to see if any error messages are produced?

Comment: The debug mode is on. In the first test I forgot to set the whole ID "entries" in the $params, debug warned me about it, after I fix this the webservice does not return me anything

Comment: sorry,checked the debug settings, and without apparent reason had returned to the original configuration.
I will try again...

Comment: Did you solved the problem ?

Comment: @Sebastian At the time of the question, I had to do directly in the database

Comment: Hi, ok, I'll probably do the same ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had same problem, but i could do it:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
$enrolment = new stdClass();
$enrolment->roleid = 5; 
$enrolment->userid = 6030;
$enrolment->courseid = 48;
$enrolments = array( $enrolment);
$params = array('enrolments' => $enrolments);

$restformat = 'json';
$functionname = 'enrol_manual_enrol_users';
$serverurl = $domainname . 'webservice/rest/server.php' . '?wstoken=' . $token . '&wsfunction=' . $functionname;

$restformat = ($restformat == 'json')?'&moodlewsrestformat=' . $restformat:'';
$handler = curl_init();
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_URL, $serverurl.$restformat);
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
$response = curl_exec($handler);
curl_close($handler);
return $response;
```

Comment: moodle api has received so many updates in recent years, may be my question is obsolete by now

Comment: Would that you were right, @Guilherme. Still a problem on 4.1. I can get it to work fine with the curl code above, but not with an API wrapper like [MoodleRest](https://github.com/llagerlof/MoodleRest).